# How to effectively store a large set of permutations?

Tags: erlang, permutation, ram, data-representation

Let's say we have a list of elements:

```
[{dog,1},{dog,2},{cat,1},{cat,2},{bird,1},{bird,2},...]
```

I would like to store all possible [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutations) of this list in the RAM.

Since the list can be pretty long (10 elements and more), it takes a lot of space to store it (factorial N).

For instance, if I have a list, which consumes about 70 bytes of space and has 12 elements, then I need `12! * 70 ~ 31 GB`. If I add just one more element to the list, then it could become unfeasible to store the permutations in the RAM.

Is there any more efficient representation to keep all the permutations in the memory than the following Erlang representation?

```
[{dog,1},{dog,2},{cat,1},{cat,2},{bird,1},{bird,2},...]
```

(I know that the atom `dog` is stored only once in the atoms table, but since it is repeated in every permutation, it takes N memory).

Maybe these permutations could be stored in some kind of byte representation? *(Sorry, I am a newbie in bytes and binaries).*

After all, it is just the same elements, but rearranged in different ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not produce them lazily? Keep an index from each list, and when asked for a new element, you produce the combination on the fly. That way, you only need to store the initial list of source elements in memory plus indices at any time.

For example (if you need to iterate over the permutations):

```
-record(perm, {list_a, list_b, index_a, index_b}).
```

Everytime you reach the maximum of `index_b`, you reset it to `0` and increment `index_a` with one. Then, accessing the Nth element of the lists (where N is the indices) you can recreate any permutation instance.

Of course, this implies that you would have to traverse the lists each time a permutation is produced. To avoid this, you could use the lists as indices themselves:

```
-record(perm2, {list_a, list_b, list_b_orig}).
```

To generate the next permutation, pop the new element from `list_b` and append it to the head of `list_a`. If `list_b` is empty, remove the head of `list_a` and start over by setting `list_b` to the original which is saved in `list_b_orig`.

Comment: Adam, could you please provide details on your answer? With my limited knowledge I only understand that I should have a (DB? Matrix?) table, which has all the unique list elements in rows and all the permutations in columns. The corresponding cells should store the exact index (place number) of the particular element in the particular list (permutation). I believe your answer implies a much more elegant solution.

Comment: See the updated post. The point is to never fully create all the permutations at once.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie, but I do not get how I should use the record structure you have provided. What should I store in list_a and in list_b? Are index_a and index_b of Erlang list data type or anything else?

Comment: Well, I was mainly trying to illustrate that all you need to keep track of which permutations you're currently at is the lists of individual element and indices (a number) pointing out the positions in the lists.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a List of N elements, there are N! permutations. So if we are able to produce a mapping from the numbers 1 to N! (or 0 to N!-1) to these permutations in a reproducable way, we wouldn't need to store N! lists of elements, but only N! numbers.

But stop - why should we store N! numbers? We don't need to store them, because they don't change. We only need the upper bound, which is defined by the biggest element index, which is N, which should be stored already in your code.

I'm sorry not to know Erlang, but [I wrote a functional algorithm in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8958309/312172) which allows to produce permutations of arbitrary size in a reproducable manner.

For example, the 123456790th permutation of the numbers (1 to 12) is List (4, 2, 1, 5, 12, 7, 10, 8, 11, 9, 3, 6).

As a special bonus, this algorithm produces the permutations in a sorted way. Just finding all permutations in reproduceable way but without order is more simple:

```
def permutationIndex (idx: Int, list: List [Int]) : List [Int] = {
  if (list.isEmpty) list else {
    val el = list (idx % list.size) 
    el :: permutationIndex (idx / list.size, list.remove (_ == el))}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe compressing it would do the job?

[Zlib](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/zlib.html) module seems to do something like this.