# Permutation rank algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

I'm struggling to find efficient algorithm for calculating the rank of a permutation, and vice versa (permutation for a given rank). Can someone give some pointers?

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8958309/312172 I made an graphic, illustrating the problem, and giving a solution in one way. If you look at the list of `related` issues on the right, you'll find many duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have repeating elements in the array?

If there are **only unique elements**, the following recursion calculates the rank of `X[m:n]` as a permutation of length `n-m+1`:

> Rank(X, m:n) = RankOfElement(X[m], X[m:n]) * Factorial(n - m) + Rank(X, (m+1):n)

Both `Rank` and `RankOfElement` are zero-based (start at 0).

Basically, `Rank(permutation) = Rank(first permutation starting with first letter of permutation) + Rank(permutation with first letter deleted)`, e.g. for string `EDCBA` that means `Rank(EDCBA) = Rank(EABCD) + Rank(DCBA)`.

This can be extended to **non-unique** cases by changing the first term:

> Rank(X, m:n) = Rank(X, (m+1):n) + ∑ over (y ∈ X[m:n], y < X[m]) of number of combinations of {X[m:n]}-{y} .

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

I just saw your comment. Nice graphic! Right what you want is a tree traversal.

Notice how each position in your permutation has a distinct level in the tree? Every path from the root to a leaf node in that tree is a possible permutation.

So this means that your 'rank' has some flexibility. You get to define it. Just make it whatever type of traversal you want over the tree (inorder, preorder, postorder, DFS,BFS) to give you a numbering of leaf nodes incremented as you go straight through each leaf node.

So just choose the traversal and ranking of your permutations to be whatever you find most natural or convenient for your application. If you can't choose, ask /dev/random which traversal you should use.

**END EDIT**

Well first it has to be thought of like a base conversion. Every permutation is at a point (it's rank). Think of binary. What's an efficient algorithm for calculating a 2 alphabet permutation over n characters? Just assign the rank and you have the permutation.

The same thing works for alphabets of other size. Obviously things are more complicated if your positions have different size alphabets, but you can still do the combinatorics :

```
total possible = pi(|a|_i) for all i in positions

|a|_i alphabet size at position i

and assuming all |a|_i are equal to b you have

rank of permutation = sigma(b**i * a_i)

a_i is actual alphabet character chosen at position i.

So over the 5 alphabet (ABCDE) 

The rank of AAAAA = 0 (or 1)
The rank of EEEED = 5**6 - 2
```

Then to get permutation from rank just use a radix formula : I seem to remember:

```
a_i = (P % b**(i+1) - P & (b**i))/(b**i)
```

If you think about it from this combinatorical and radix perspective, you can't go wrong, even in more complex cases. Just take whatever rank you want and convert it into the base that's appropriate for your alphabet. You may be interested in [Mixed Radix Conversion on Wikipedia, here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_radix)