# Find Kth lexographically smallest string

Tags: algorithm

Given N A'sand N B's How to find Kth lexographically smallest string of all the strings of length 2*N.

Like if N=2 It means we have 2A and 2B then if we need to find say 2(=K) smallest lexographically smallest string then answer is "ABBA".

Explanation :

```
0.AABB
1.ABAB
2.ABBA
3.BAAB
4.BABA
5.BBAA
```

One way is to just simply find all the strings and sort them and then find kth smallest string.But is their a better way to do it ?

Comment: Why ABBA and not AABB?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compute rank of a combination?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143142/compute-rank-of-a-combination)

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I think its bit different.

Comment: @BlackBear See explanation

Comment: It's not different at all if you read it and think about it for more than a minute.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752016/finding-permutation-of-a-set-of-0-and-1-given-index-with-on/24770852#24770852

Comment: Isn't this question from an on-going contest at Hackerrank.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let us start from left. You have N A's and N B's.
First compute the number of strings possible with A as their first character. It is 
`(2n-1)!/((n-1)!(n)!)` If this value is greater than K, then our string will start with K otherwise it will start with B. Now, to move on we have two cases

Case1: If it starts with A, then the number of A's to check in next step will decrease by 1. And we will check for `(2n-2)!/((n-2)!(n!))` Value of `K` need not be updated.

Case2: If it starts with B, then the number of B's to check in next step will decrease by 1. And we will check for `(2n-2)!/((n-1)!(n-1)!)` Value of `1` will be updated to `K - (2n-1)!/((n-1)!(n)!)` and we proceed with new values.

Complexity issues: We need not compute the factorials every time newly. Since we see that the factorial in numerator is decreasing consistently we can divide it with `(2n - stepNo)` and get next step's numerator. Similarly for either of the denominators.