# How to quickly generate a random permutation moving each element with a distance less than K?

Tags: python, arrays, pytorch, permutation

I know the following PyTorch API can perform a global random shuffle for 1D array [0, ... , n-1]:

```py
torch.randperm(n)
```

but I'm confused on how to quickly generate a random permutation, such that each element of the shuffled array satisfying:

```py
K = 10  # should be positive
shuffled_array = rand_perm_func(n, K)  # a mysterious function
for i in range(n):
    print(abs(shuffled_array[i] - i) < K)  # should be True for each i
```

which means that each element is moved with a distance less than K. Does there exists fast implementations for 1D arrays and 2D arrays?

---

Thanks to @PM 2Ring, I wrote the following code:

```py
import torch

# randomly produces a 1-D permutation index array,
# such that each element of the shuffled array has
# a distance less than K from its original location
def rand_perm(n, K):
    o = torch.arange(0, n)
    if K <= 1:
        return o
    while True:
        p = torch.randperm(n)
        d = abs(p - o) < K
        if bool(d.all()):
            return p

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(10):
        print(rand_perm(10, 2))
```

but it seems that when n is large, and K is small, the generation will take a very long time. Does there exists a more efficient implementation?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.
Asking for software recommendations or references is *specifically* listed as off-topic.

Comment: I don't know if there's a fast way to do this. There are various algorithms to compute the rank of a permutation (its lexicographic index), or produce a permutation from its rank, see eg  https://stackoverflow.com/q/8940470/4014959 & some of the questions linked there. However, when those algorithms are looking for a slot for the next item they skip over slots that are already occupied, and I think that makes it hard to adapt them to your restriction.

Comment: FWIW, it's not too hard to produce your restricted permutations, using recursion. If you need multiple permutations for a given (n, K) pair, it's more efficient to produce them using a (recursive) generator, rather than producing each permutation from scratch. That also has the benefit of not producing duplicates.

Comment: Thank you~ I wrote a small function above, but the generating speed could be very slow in some cases.

Comment: No worries. Your approach is (probably) ok when K is large (relative to n) and thus the probability of `randperm` producing a valid permutation is high. But otherwise, you end up rejecting most permutations, which wastes a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a recursive generator in plain Python (i.e. not using PyTorch or Numpy) that produces permutations of `range(n)` satisfying the given constraint.

First, we create a list `out` to contain the output sequence, setting each slot in `out` to -1 to indicate that slot is unused. Then, for each value `i` we create a list `avail` of indices in the permitted range that aren't already occupied. For each `j` in `avail`, we set `out[j] = i` and recurse to place the next `i`. When `i == n`, all the `i` have been placed, so we've reached the end of the recursion, and `out` contains a valid solution, which gets propagated back up the recursion tree.

```
from random import shuffle

def rand_perm_gen(n, k):
    out = [-1] * n
    def f(i):
        if i == n:
            yield out
            return

        lo, hi = max(0, i-k+1), min(n, i+k)
        avail = [j for j in range(lo, hi) if out[j] == -1]
        if not avail:
            return
        shuffle(avail)
        for j in avail:
            out[j] = i
            yield from f(i+1)
            out[j] = -1

    yield from f(0)

def test(n=10, k=3, numtests=10):
    for j, a in enumerate(rand_perm_gen(n, k), 1):
        print("\n", j, a)
        for i, u in enumerate(a):
            print(f"{i}: {u} -> {(u - i)}")
        if j == numtests:
            break

test()
```

#### Typical output

```
 1 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 8 -> 1
8: 9 -> 1
9: 7 -> -2

 2 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 9 -> 2
8: 8 -> 0
9: 7 -> -2

 3 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 9, 7, 8]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 9 -> 2
8: 7 -> -1
9: 8 -> -1

 4 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 8, 7, 9]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 8 -> 1
8: 7 -> -1
9: 9 -> 0

 5 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 7 -> 0
8: 8 -> 0
9: 9 -> 0

 6 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 5, 4, 7, 9, 8]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 5 -> 0
6: 4 -> -2
7: 7 -> 0
8: 9 -> 1
9: 8 -> -1

 7 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 9, 8]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 7 -> 2
6: 4 -> -2
7: 5 -> -2
8: 9 -> 1
9: 8 -> -1

 8 [1, 0, 3, 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 8, 9]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 6 -> 2
5: 7 -> 2
6: 4 -> -2
7: 5 -> -2
8: 8 -> 0
9: 9 -> 0

 9 [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 9, 8]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 5 -> 1
5: 6 -> 1
6: 4 -> -2
7: 7 -> 0
8: 9 -> 1
9: 8 -> -1

 10 [1, 0, 3, 2, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8, 9]
0: 1 -> 1
1: 0 -> -1
2: 3 -> 1
3: 2 -> -1
4: 5 -> 1
5: 6 -> 1
6: 4 -> -2
7: 7 -> 0
8: 8 -> 0
9: 9 -> 0
```

Here's a [live version](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxtUstuwyAQvPsrVj5Bg6VYvUVy1VN_Io0iWi_J-gEWhqpVlH8vYOdhyXtBDLuzs7Moa3qwUtfhoH4w1sF49kp1mGU1qvR0HND2xxNqpgW0fJdBCOMdVLAvygO8gE5QzFeM5oQYpICgqkA_oBh_hF0dGRaoReetzu5YZwScQzn08pdtBVDRbkouoKckhDYtv-fKH0ld1NOAMhYaIB2ln5BNLDxKCQ33zSHqCaqfNWrjJobdmqDbdfaFpcxH63u_FYZbR6CV-VW0PvgVhlovKsrJjEX6lmfZO2mHVn67tCKHo2O6KoNFbfUqQPs-QmNCpHfm6IdaOqw-ZDfivJ2kOjxH4RgqAp1DtrJtAeXTQgcbWrP8U-cilS9tIAF-SSj50pCpXuUXuu7g4q9QvMGFeSiA-DXnz0tp0seZZ1myfFmU7T8Mnriu&lang=sage) running on SageMathCell.

This approach is faster than generating all permutations and filtering them, but it is still slow for large `n`. You can improve the speed by removing the `shuffle` call, in which case the yielded permutations are in lexicographic order.

If you just want a single solution, use `next`, eg

```
perm = next(rand_perm_gen(10, 3))
```

Note that all solutions share the same `out` list. So if you need to save those solutions in a list you have to copy them, eg

```
perms = [seq.copy() for seq in rand_perm_gen(5, 2)]
```